# Matter antimatter fundamental and adjoint representation (Hermitian Anti-Hermitian)

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I’m struggling with the following. I read in “The Standard Model: A Primer by Cliff Burgess”, page 493, that fermion fields in the fundamental representation can be thought of as column vector(s) (spinor) left-multiplied by their corresponding adjoint Hermitian generator ($a_{ij}$ = $\bar{a_{ji}}$). Then it says that the antifundamental representation is more conveniently thought of as a row vector right-multiplied by an anti-Hermitian matrix ($a_{ij}$ = $- \bar{a_{ji}}$), e.g. antiquarks coming in an anti-color triplet anti-red, anti-green and anti-blue. So far so good. Now, a Dirac fermion field comes with 4 independent components (${\psi_L}{\bar{\psi_R}}$ + ${\psi_R}{\bar{\psi_L}}$): LH matter and RH anti-matter coupling to W bosons, and RH matter and LH anti-matter not coupling to the weak interaction.

To continue the same line of thought, would it be correct to say that (1) LH matter fields are represented by a column vector left-multiplied by a Hermitian (transposed complex conjugated) generator; (2) RH anti-matter by a row vector right-multiplied by an Anti-Hermitian generator and then (3) RH matter by a column vector - this time - right-multiplied by a Hermitian generator and (4) LH anti-matter by a row vector left-multiplied by an Anti-Hermitian generator?

If not, how should I correctly interpret this? And where could I read more about this